# syntax error in expression when trying to select from a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying this code but I don't know why this problem is occuring.

```
 DataRow[] filterRow = Productdt.Select("PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME where CATEGORY_ID=" + catID);
```

Is it because of the where clause?

Comment: What is the value of `catID` here?

Comment: catID=1 that's the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not give column names to select by just the filter criteria in select method.

```
DataRow[] filterRow = Productdt.Select("CATEGORY_ID=" + catID);
```

The criteria to use to filter the rows. For examples on how to filter rows, see [DataView RowFilter](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) Syntax [C#], [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You are read more about expression [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: why i can't give column names ? ?